# Why is a div id messing my inline-block up?

Tags: html, css

My code is here (I'm a newbie just playing with some stuff I've learned; I realize this is hardly a work of art, my links all link back to Codecademy, etc - they're just placeholders) Here's the CSS:

```
head {background-color:#eed393;}

#links {display:inline-block;
 margin-left:35px;
  margin-top:8px;
  margin-bottom:40px;
vertical-align:top;
}

div:hover {opacity:0.8;
}

#locationhours {
  border:none;
  border-radius:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
 text-align:center; font-family:Georgia;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#724d20}

#menu {border:none;
  border-radius:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:55px;
 text-align:center; font-family:Georgia;
  padding-top:15px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#724d20}

#catering {border:none;
  border-radius:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:55px;
  text-align:center;
font-family:Georgia;
  padding-top:15px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#724d20}


a:link {text-decoration:none;
  color:#b0dddf;}

a.fill_div {display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<head> 
  <div id:"links">
   <div id="locationhours";><a href="www.codecademy.com"     class="fill_div">Location & Hours</a> </div>

    <div id="menu";><a href="www.codecademy.com"     class="fill_div">Menu</a></div>

  <div id="catering";><a href="www.codecademy.com"     class="fill_div">Catering</a> </div>

  <div id="infocontact";><a href="www.codecademy.com"     class="fill_div">Info & <br> Contact</a> </div>

  </div>
```

I have a div id called #links that I am trying to use for aspects of my links I want to make universal. As you can see, although I am using inline-block, I can't get the links to be in a horizontal line; instead, they bunch up in a vertical line. If I put "div" rather than "#links" in my CSS, the inline-block works, but I'm going to have other div elements I want to use later that I don't want to apply the aspects for the links to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo in the 2nd line of HTML `id:` should be `id=`. Maybe that will fix it?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, but that didn't solve it unfortunately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The CSS `display: inline` must be applied to each individual member of the list you want to make inline. The `display` property is best described as the relationship of a node in its parent, **not** the relationship of all children. Furthermore, `display` is a non-inheritable property (see [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)), so applying it to the parent node `#links` won't affect its children (`#locationhours`, `#menu`, etc.) whatsoever.

When you changed it to affect `div`, you unknowingly were affecting all of the children, since they too are divs. To quickly fix this problem without any inline CSS, set each list member's div to the class `.listmem`, like this...

```
<div id="locationhours" class="listmem">
```

...so adding this to your CSS should quickly fix the problem:

```
.listmem {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Adding that code does not fix the issue. Did you make a demo?

Comment: Sorry forgot that my code would affect `a` rather than `div`

Comment: Hanoncs: Thanks for spotting the : issue and the unnecessary ;s. ...really not sure how they got there, other than me getting all css-happy within my html!

Comment: BradzTech - that seems to work! I'm still getting to grips with how ids, classes, parents and children all behave. And thanks for the info regarding display!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of your code now inline: http://jsfiddle.net/co738b5s/1/

I found lots of issues. In the "links" div you were using : instead of = to add the id. Also, when you are adding ID's and classes, you do not need the ; that you used. See my html for corrections.

```
 <div id="links">
   <div id="locationhours" class="inline">
       <a href="www.codecademy.com" class="fill_div">Location & Hours</a> </div>

    <div id="menu" class="inline">
        <a href="www.codecademy.com" class="fill_div">Menu</a>
     </div>

  <div id="catering" class="inline">
      <a href="www.codecademy.com" class="fill_div">Catering</a> 
     </div>


  <div id="infocontact" class="inline">
      <a href="www.codecademy.com" class="fill_div">Info & <br/> Contact</a>
      </div>
</div>




//Had to make a new class for all the menu divs

head {background-color:#eed393;}
 .inline {
     float:left;


 }

#links {

 margin-left:35px;
  margin-top:8px;
  margin-bottom:40px;
vertical-align:top;
}

div:hover {opacity:0.8;
}

#locationhours {
  border:none;
  border-radius:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
 text-align:center; font-family:Georgia;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#724d20}

#menu {border:none;
  border-radius:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:55px;
 text-align:center; font-family:Georgia;
  padding-top:15px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#724d20}

#catering {border:none;
  border-radius:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:55px;
  text-align:center;
font-family:Georgia;
  padding-top:15px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#724d20}

#infocontact {border:none;
  border-radius:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:55px;
  text-align:center;
font-family:Georgia;
  padding-top:15px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#724d20}

a:link {text-decoration:none;
  color:#b0dddf;}

a.fill_div {;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
  text-decoration: none;
}
```